# How to remove crystal water from potassium ferrocyanide trihydrate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

For potassium ferrocyanide/yellow prussiate/potassium hexacyanoferrate(II), I identified only commercial sources of the trihydrate, $\ce{K4[Fe(CN)6] * 3H2O}$.

What are the conditions (temperature, because I guess heating in an oven might suffice) to completely remove the crystal water in this chemical?

Comment: Anhydrous trihydrate is a glaring example of an oxymoron, much like "Little Big Horn" or  "honest politician".

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: One suitable approach is to look up the information provided by the chemical suppliers *about the trihydrate* (example [Millipore/Sigma](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/substance/potassiumhexacyanoferrateiitrihydrate4223914459951?context=product)) and to note the CAS registry number.  Use this number in chemistry relevant databases (e.g., *Reaxys* by Elsevier, *Scifinder* by the American Chemical Society) to look up primary references describing this (*if* you really need this, check with your TA) in a research library.  As the librarian of your uni for assistance how to use these sources.

Answer (score 2):

[Just heat it.](https://www.911metallurgist.com/blog/ferrocyanides)

[image]

Alternatively refer to [this paper.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01915163)